# PipedInputStream.read() returns -1

Tags: java, stream, pipe, eof

How can `PipedInputStream.read()` return -1 if I had not closed any streams? `closedByReader` is false, `closedByWriter` is false, `connected` is true, but it returns -1; Why it thinks I finished? What is the condition when `read()` should return negative?

**EDIT 1**

Here is the code of the library function

```
public synchronized int read(byte b[], int off, int len)  throws IOException {
if (b == null) {
    throw new NullPointerException();
} else if (off < 0 || len < 0 || len > b.length - off) {
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
} else if (len == 0) {
    return 0;
}

    /* possibly wait on the first character */
int c = read();
if (c < 0) {
    return -1;
}
b[off] = (byte) c;
int rlen = 1;
while ((in >= 0) && (len > 1)) {

    int available; 

    if (in > out) {
    available = Math.min((buffer.length - out), (in - out));
    } else {
    available = buffer.length - out;
    }

    // A byte is read beforehand outside the loop
    if (available > (len - 1)) {
    available = len - 1;
    }
    System.arraycopy(buffer, out, b, off + rlen, available);
    out += available;
    rlen += available; 
    len -= available;

    if (out >= buffer.length) {
    out = 0;
    }
    if (in == out) {
            /* now empty */
    in = -1;
    }
}
return rlen;
}
```

I can't trace variable values yet, but I can see how it jumps from line to line in Eclipse debugger. So I saw that it exits at the last line. Only one `while` loop executes. Since we have `rlen=1` before while, hence the only reason it can change is in `rlen += available` line. This variable shuld equals `-2`. I saw that it visits `available = len - 1` line last. So, `len` should be `-1`, but pass `2048`...

**EDIT 2**

Of course, error was mine and was absolutely in the other place. Actually `PipedInputStream` was wrapped into `AudioInputStream` which was erroneously configured as being of fixed size. Reaching the size was causing end of stream condition.

Comment: In that case `read()` should block (waiting writer to write something).

Comment: How is it possible to send `EOF` to binary stream?

Comment: You're right, the situation you're describing seems impossible. Are you sure you're not misinterpreting anything? Maybe if you show some code that does this someone would be able to help more.

Comment: Of course I am not sure. But how to check some obvious reasons?

Comment: An SSCCE shouldn't be the JDK code, but how you actually *use* that code..

Comment: I know but I can't localize error yet. I do very complex transformations in many threads. I will recompile `rt.jar` to see what is happening.

Answer (score -3):

well, InputStream would have to return -1 if the next byte on stream it was reading was -1. If your stream is not closed, connected is true, I think this is just data you are seeing

Comment: How did you know that? Where it is said that I can't send 0xFF byte over the stream?

Comment: May be you don't know read function prototype? Here it is http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html

Comment: I.e. it is impossible to mix return status and returned data.

Comment: @Suzan No it's not. We read `bytes` but read returns `int`s. Every possible byte is in the range 0-255 for that purpose, while the return value is -1 if the stream is closed. Works perfectly fine to mix return code and data.

Comment: @Voo So in my case the stream is not closed. How can it return `-1` then?

Comment: @Suzan As far as I can see PipedReader doesn't have any `closedByReader/Writer` method, so no idea where you get that information. But returning -1 means it got closed (not necessarily explicitly by the user but by an error, etc.).

Comment: @user1291492 Yeah isn't it great that the function returns an `int` and doesn't sign extend the byte? `255 == 255 != -1` for a 4byte value.

Comment: @Voo, `closedBy...` are private fields of the class `PipedInputStream` which are shown in Eclipse debugger.

Comment: @Voo I was answering suzan's question about how you could return -1

Comment: @Suzan And that field has to be set by the writing thread (or the reader on close). Doesn't seem especially safe to work in all kinds of error situations. I'd post some SSCCE that demonstrates the problem, code helps here.